# Powershell consuming webservice - missing return value

Tags: web-services, powershell

Consuming a simple webservice using powershell. It is supposed to return 2 values, but powershell only shows one. SOAPUI works fine, shows two values.  If I don't pass as [ref] the call errors. Not sure why this is?

```
$URL = "https://nonpublic/wsdl/location"
$URI = New-Object System.Uri($URL);
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$webproxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Namespace webproxy-class ssl
## webservice to return two values related to passed value
$val = "ide-550"
$result = $webproxy.getinfo([ref]$val)
$result   ## <-- only one value
```

EDIT: get member output - statustype getinfo(string [ref] val).

Comment: [ref] means reference. When you call the function it's going to pass back into your $val variable the value gotten by getinfo. it actually modify's the variable see this ss64 link it does a good job of explaining this: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-ref.html

Comment: Can you add `$webproxy | Get-Member | ? name -eq getinfo | select -expand definition` to your question?

Comment: I get that [ref] is reference. I don't get why I am forced to use this. I THINK values should be passed back as an array. Its perplexing how soapui works and this does not.